# Why does my SQL select query return only one row?

Tags: sql

Here is my SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM articles article
JOIN article_translations translation 
     ON article.id = translation.article_id
     AND translation.lang = :lang
     AND translation.date = (SELECT MAX(date)
                             FROM article_translations at_temp
                             WHERE at_temp.lang = :lang
                               AND article.id = translation.article_id)
```

It always returns only one row, but I have multiple rows on my article table. Why?

(If I only do `SELECT * FROM articles` it returns multiple rows)

Comment: `SELECT *` always return all columns. Do you mean return rows ?

Comment: Yes sorry, it was a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the last condition:

```
AND article.id = translation.article_id
```

is wrong.
Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles a JOIN article_translations t
ON a.id = t.article_id AND t.lang = :lang
AND t.date = (SELECT MAX(tt.date) FROM article_translations tt WHERE tt.lang = t.lang AND tt.article_id = t.article.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: I guess problem is with your correlated subquery =>

```
SELECT *
FROM articles article
    JOIN article_translations translation
        ON article.id = translation.article_id
        AND translation.lang = :lang
        AND translation.date = (
            SELECT MAX(date)
            FROM article_translations at_temp
                where article.id = at_temp.article_id
                  AND at_temp.lang = :lang
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because only one row in `articles` matches the condition in the `ON` clause of the `JOIN` to `article_translations`.

If you want to select all rows from `articles`, you can use `LEFT JOIN`, which keeps all rows on the left side of the query (table before the `LEFT JOIN` clause - in your case `articles`). Those rows, that do not match any rows from `article_translations` will have `NULL` values in all `article_translations` columns.

Comment: I think that all my query is bad, what i want is to select the last translation of each article how can i do that ? Your solution works but it's strange because every article has a translation

Comment: `WHERE at_temp.lang = :lang AND article.id = translation.article_id` looks very suspect. Presumably that last predicate was supposed to reference `at_temp`

Comment: Wp, it was the problem (forpas post the same answer, so I will accept his answer), thanks